# Нажать кнопку или на кнопку?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Вдруг вчера меня заело: а как правильно — "нажать НА кнопку" или просто "нажать кнопку"? У кого какие соображения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Ожегова: НАЖАТЬ,  сов.  что  и  на  кого-что.  Давя, притиснуть, надавить. Н. кнопку и на кнопку. 
КОММЕНТАРИЙ. Попробуем ответить на вопрос, имеют ли эти варианты разные оттенки смысла. Это В.п. - беспредложный и предложный. При отсутствии предлога мы воздействуем на объект целиком, а при наличии предлога "НА" воздействуем на его поверхность. Поэтому мне кажется, что технически более точным (и результативным) является нажатие кнопки, а в быту можно на нее нажимать.